# sorting is not working for column which is having hyperlink on column data in ng2 smart table angular

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

i have one column named "Link" is having link but sorting is not working for this column. please help

```
  data = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Leanne Graham',
  username: 'Bret',
  link: '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>',
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Ervin Howell',
  username: 'Antonette',
  link: '<a href="https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin">Ng2 Admin</a>',
}];

 settings = {
columns: {
  id: {
    title: 'ID',
   
  },
  name: {
    title: 'Full Name',
  
  },
  username: {
    title: 'User Name',
  },
  link: {
    title: 'Link',
    type: 'html',
  
  },
},
```

[hyperlink example in ng2-smart-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzIqu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ng2-smart-table but my guess is that the sorting is using the entire link value for sorting, instead of the text displayed.

Regardless if that's the case or not, try looking at `compareFunction`:

```
link: {
  title: 'Link',
  type: 'html',
  
  compareFunction(direction: any, a: any, b: any) => {
    //gets the text in the link element
    let aText = $("<div></div>").html(a).find("a").text().toLowerCase();
    let bText = $("<div></div>").html(b).find("a").text().toLowerCase();

    if (aText < bText) {
      return -1 * direction;
    }
    if (aText > bText) {
      return direction;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: but actually if we enter some data in upper case (for example :" Ankita") and some data in lowercase (for example : "ankita" ) so sorting is not working properly.. please help..

Comment: yes i have done...   let aText = $("<div></div>").html(a).find("a").text();
    let bText = $("<div></div>").html(b).find("a").text();
 let first = aText.toLowerCase();
 let second = bText.toLowerCase();

    if (first < second) {
      return -1 * direction;
    }
    if (first > second) {
      return direction;
    }
    return 0;
  }   ................. it is working for me ,, now sorting is completed

Comment: Great! I updated my answer to match your changes :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

maybe that could help you   [enter link description here](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/projects/demo/src/app/pages/examples/custom-edit-view/custom-render.component.ts)

[image]

Comment: Please paste code as text and format as code. Don’t just embed screenshots of code. It makes it harder to read, search, and reference.